# How do I get a local Maven package to bring in its dependencies?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have written a series of classes that I want to turn into a company library. Managing all it's dependencies was a pain so I made a Maven project for it to be handled automatically.

I have packaged my library project into a .jar and added it to my local Maven repository. I can now list it in my application project's pom.xml, it get's brought in just like any other dependency and works great.

The problem is the dependencies of my library do not get brought in. It seems like this should be straight forward but trying to copy other packages in the Maven repository doesn't work.

Right now my jar consists of two directories:

```
com\company\package\Main.class
```

And:

```
META-INF\maven\com.company\package\pom.xml
```

Where do I need to put the `pom.xml` file for Maven to go get my dependency's dependencies? Is there something else in the `.jar` build that I am missing?

Comment: How is the module added to the other project? If it's not done via maven, but simply by adding the jar, the transitive dependencies won't be added. You would have to create a fat jar(jar-with-dependencies using maven-assembly-plugin), but better option is to convert all projects to maven.

Comment: All projects are Maven projects. In all cases modules are added via pom.xml. I am not familiar with fat jars. I will look into that.

Comment: In that case, the dependencies should be added automatically unless they are scoped as provided.

Comment: Fat jar is not what I want. That's more or less how I was handling it originally and it felt really messy.

As far as I can tell I have matched how the other dependencies are built but I am obviously missing something in the .jar or some step in getting Maven to work properly.

Comment: This is a useful command for analyzing maven dependencies: `mvn dependency:tree`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Maven POM file (`pom.xml`), which describes the project/module, is usually placed in the root directory.

The POM file can then be picked up by your Maven installation, which will automatically configure the project, which means also downloading dependencies from their repositories.

For an example of an artifact deployed to a repository, see
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.5.RELEASE/

Comment: That's where it went by default. I moved it to match the other modules in the Maven repositories. I will move it back and try again.

Comment: When I create a project the pom.xml goes in root. When Maven brings in .jar files they all have the pom.xml buried under META-INF.

Comment: @kgoodwin it doesn't matter at all. When you "install" your JAR in repository, the POM file is alongside the JAR (it's external, in the same containing directory usually)

Comment: @kgoodwin instead, you can use "deploy" to install in a remote repository.

Comment: Thank you LppEdd. The file I needed wasn't pom.xml at all but <package>.pom. I moved the .xml file and renamed it and now it works.

Comment: @kgoodwin good to know! For example, here is how Spring Core is packaged in the repository at Maven Central http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.5.RELEASE/

Comment: If you use Maven properly this shouldn't be an issue. My problem was Eclipse would not generate a Maven project without JRE version conflicts so I tried to make my own Maven artifact without fully understanding how it works. Now we are using the convert function to make our non-conflicting projects into Maven projects and everything is mostly happy.

Comment: @kgoodwin thanks for the update! Sounds good! P.S. Switch to Intellij :P